# Eclipse - Moving class files to their recommended package

Tags: java, eclipse, class, package

[image]

I have plenty of class files that did not come with a project file, so I want to be able to move these classes into their first "recommended" package move destination, these classes have different packages so I cannot just create one package and move them all there. Is there a way to move them all into their corresponding packages?